# Adding two numbers in Perl

Tags: perl

I have written the following Perl Code:

```
print "Enter two numbers \n";
$choise = <STDIN>;
$choise2 = <STDIN>;
$res = add($choise1, $choise2);
print "\n and the result is $res";

sub add
{
    ($x,$y) = @_;
    $res = $x + $y;
    return $res;    
}
```

but when I enter two inputs the output is wrong. For example adding 4 and 5, the output I am getting is 5, not 9. why?

Comment: Why the result should be 5?

Comment: no , the output of my program is 5 , which is wrong

Comment: You set the input to `choise` and use the variable `choise1`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Learn to use the `strict` pragma and you'll save yourself useless frustration.

Comment: Also, "choice" is usually spelled with two "c"s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$res = add($choise1 , $choise2);
```

to:

```
$res = add($choise , $choise2);
```

You really should `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the begining of all your scripts.

Answer (score 3):

There's a reason why everyone keeps parroting "use warnings; use strict;" to beginners.

You've got half a dozen problems with this script most of which will be revealed by doing so.

In any case, your first step when confused should be to establish exactly what is happening. As someone has just mentioned above the basic error is a typo in a variable name. Just printing the contents of $x, $y in your sub would have shown that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter two number \n";
my $choise1 = <STDIN> ;
my $choise2 = <STDIN> ;
my $res = add($choise1 , $choise2);
print "\n and the result is $res\n" ;

sub add
{
    my ($x,$y) = @_;
    # printing $x,$y here would have shown the problem
    my $res = $x + $y ;
    return $res ;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the first number as $choise but you are passing it in to add as $choise1.  This ends up as 0. So in you example 0 + 5 = 5.

Answer (score 0):

**Modified Program**

```
     print "Enter two number \n";
    $choise1 = <STDIN> ;
    $choise2 = <STDIN> ;
    $res = add($choise1 , $choise2);
    print "\n and the result is $res" ;


    sub add
    {
        ($x,$y) = @_;
        $res = $x + $y ;
        return $res ;
    }
```

OUTPUT::
root@test-virtual-machine:/home/test/Prasad_sample# perl sample_input.pl
Enter two number
4
5

and the result is 9

Problem in your code at following Line 
$choise =  ;

You have mention "$choise" instead of "$choise1".You have to pass valid parameters to subroutine in perl.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ why are you running a script as root … that you just copied off the internet … without even cleaning up all problems with it? Please adopt better security practices, or one day you'll accidentally `rm -rf /` (or worse).